# Tensorflow precision metrics not initializing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written the following Tensorflow code that performs logistic regression on a custom dataset.

```
def logi_regression(data, labels, test_data, test_labels, learning_rate, 
                batch_size, training_epochs, display_step):

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, data.shape[1]])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, labels.shape[1]])

# Weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([data.shape[1], 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))

# Logistic Model
pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# Error function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, 
                                                              labels=y))

# Gradient Descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Initialise global variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init_l = tf.local_variables_initializer()

# Training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(init_l)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(data.shape[0]/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            # The next_data_batch is a custom made function
            batch_xs, batch_ys = next_data_batch(batch_size, 
                                                 data, labels)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                                          y: batch_ys})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    prediction = tf.round(tf.sigmoid(pred))
    correct = tf.cast(tf.equal(prediction, y), dtype=tf.float32)
    _, precision = tf.metrics.precision(y, prediction)
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct)
    avg_prec = tf.reduce_mean(precision)
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: test_data, y: test_labels}))
    print("Average Precision Score:", avg_prec.eval({x: test_data, y: test_labels}))
```

But, even though I get the correct output from the training (`Epoch: xxxx cost= 0.xxxx`) and from the test set (`Accuracy:0.xxx`). When the program tries to calculate the precision it returns an error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value precision/true_positives/count     [[node
>   precision/true_positives/AssignAdd (defined at
>   :54) ]]

Therefore, the problem is in the final lines that I have added the (`_, precision = tf.metrics.precision(y, prediction)`). I have tried various suggestions from Stackoverflow posts but nothing has worked. It must be a silly coding mistake but due to my inexperience with Tensorflow I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines creating nodes in the tensorflow-graph should be before the 'tf.global_variables_initializer()' statement to be part of the default graph. Move the following lines to above the initializer and it will work:

```
# Test model
    prediction = tf.round(tf.sigmoid(pred))
    correct = tf.cast(tf.equal(prediction, y), dtype=tf.float32)
    _, precision = tf.metrics.precision(y, prediction)
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct)
    avg_prec = tf.reduce_mean(precision)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But it is weird because eventhough 'accuracy', 'correct' and 'prediction' worked fine. Although, they were after the initializer. The problem was with 'avg_prec' and 'precision' only. 

Shouldn't both metrics work similarly?

Comment: 'accuracy' and 'correct' are operations, but don't contain any variables to initialize. 'tf.metrics.precision' does. From doc:
`The precision function creates two local variables, true_positives and false_positives, that are used to compute the precision`. I'd suggest to keep most or all tensorflow operations within the graph definition (before starting a tf.Session).

Comment: Also, when asking for help in this way, I strongly suggest either including a complete runable code example.